# Get many values with 1 query

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

```
+----+-----------+-----+
| ID | name      |price|
+----+-----------+-----+
|  1 |dest_tahiti|  10 |
|  2 |dest_bora  |  20 |
| ...|   ...     | ... | 
+----+-----------+-----+
```

```
$price="SELECT price FROM rates WHERE name IN('dest_tahiti','dest_bora', ...) ";
$price_prep= mysqli_query($connect,$price);
$price_result=  mysqli_fetch_array($price_prep);


echo $prix_result["price"] //Just display price for dest_tahiti with WHERE = 'dest_tahiti';
echo $prix_result["price"] //Just display price for dest_bora  with WHERE = 'dest_bora';
```

I would like to **custom** *values* `WHERE name = ...` for **same query** **with `mysqli_fetch_array`** ?
You can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include the name as an output in your query. And after that iterate over the returned rows and build an array where the index is the name and the value is the price.

```php
$price = "SELECT name, price FROM rates WHERE name IN('dest_tahiti','dest_bora', ...) ";
$price_result = mysqli_query($connect, $price);
$prix_result = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($price_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $prix_result[ $row['name'] ] = $row['price'];
}

echo $prix_result['dest_tahiti'];
echo $prix_result['dest_bora'];
```